# Is there an OpenGL (or another good working) solution for coverflow?

Tags: android, opengl-es, coverflow, android-adapterview

All coverflow solutions I've found had bugs and were based on the Gallery view (which is deprecated and is very inefficient, especially with memory,read [**here**](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3376) and [**here**](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9a9be423fcdadb98)) and they have bugs when you set some sizes for the images .

The only one that works is a [**paid library**](http://www.droidux.com/products/widgets-list-of-widgets/galleryflows), but it doesn't support hardware acceleration (at least not now) , so it becomes very slow on many devices, especially those with a high resolution.

I've also found [**a solution which uses openGL**](http://stuartowen.com/home/?p=29), but I can't find out where is the code and how to contact the creator.

Another solution I've found is to use the [**Carousel**](http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip&can=1&q=) example , but it uses Renderscript which is also deprecated, plus I need a solution that will work on older APIs .

Is there a working solution which doesn't have those issues? Maybe something that uses OpenGL?